# Django filter by conditional annotation

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Is it possible to have "conditional" annotation in Django?
Let's say, there are following models

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   published = models.BooleanField()
```

now I'd like to select some limited (filtered) queryset of authors, and annotate them with both total books count and published books count, for later usage (like applying filters on the authors queryset, or ordering it). Something like

`Author.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'a').annotate(total_books = Count('books')).annotate(published_books = Count('books', <here published=true filter>))`

Is that possible anyhow?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I have a similar situation. I have files attached to an item, the files can be deleted with a deleted Boolean field. When I annotate on the files to get their status it is including the deleted ones, even though the File Object Manager tells Django to ignore deleted file unless specified.

Answer (score 1):

Django's ORM calls translate into SQL. If it can't be accomplished with an SQL query, it usually means you can't do it with the ORM as well. What you are requesting is a different `where` clause (unless I'm missing something or misunderstanding), requiring a different query. This leaves you with 2 options:

1. Run 2 different queries (with different `filter()` arguments)
2. If this is an "expensive" query that you don't want to run twice, you can just pull the data from the DB once and preform the aggregate in normal python code.

Comment: Cant edit question from my mobile. Anyway, Id like it to generate sql with two counts on left outer joins to articles table, one of them with condition published=true..

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple thought, you can try:

```
Author.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'a').\
    annotate(total_books = Count('books')).\
    annotate(published_books = Count('books__published'))
```

Since `BooleanField` is written as 0/1 integer, it may do the job. Or it may not :) Just try it inside your code.